# IE10 WebResource.axd does not download. Causes Error "'WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions' is undefined"

Tags: internet-explorer-10

It seems that in our case link buttons get this error in IE 10 only.  In the couple hours of research I've done this appears to be a IE 10 bug.

[Bug and Fix: ASP.NET fails to detect IE10 causing _doPostBack is undefined JavaScript error or maintain FF5 scrollbar position](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)

I tried to download the KB hot fix and cannot, I get a page not found message.  I also tried downloading the browser files in the blog post, the fix did not work.

This issue only occurs on our win server 2008 IIS 7 servers
iis 6 win server 2003 work fine.

Anyone else run into this and have a fix for it?

Answer (score 2):

So you've walked through the steps Hanselman outlined here?
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

We had this same problem, got the hotfix files, applied them to the server and all is well for us.

Comment: I couldn't get the hot fix to download so I tried the manual steps in his blog and it did not work.  I just got the download to work and in fact it does fix this issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The hot fix in Hanselman's blog fixed my issue.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I tried every patch that I've seen listed on the internet, including the ones listed in the referenced blog.  The only thing that actually seemed to work was installing the .NET 4.5 Framework on the server.

Get it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Hope this saves someone a few of the hours I've lost on this one.